# AutoHotkey Script to open chrome with different profiles

Tags: autohotkey

How can this procedure be done with ahk script

**If I press Ctrl+Q**

1. It opens chrome.
2. Selects Mayank Profile, [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozpi5.png), opens [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) and [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) in it.
3. As of now Mayank chrome is running, then Selects Julia profile and opens [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com) and [www.yahoomail.com](http://www.yahoomail.com).
   As of now Now Three chrome will be opening right, One the chrome that is launched firstly, Mayank secondly, Julia the third. As I have to work with these two chromes(2nd and 3rd)
4. It closes the first chrome.
   and I end up having only two chromes opened and julia is activated which contains [www.gmail.com](http://www.gmail.com) and [www.yahoomail.com](http://www.yahoomail.com) as shown in the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEFnV.png)

Note: All this happens if I press **Ctrl+Q**

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag for `chrome.exe` when you launch it, so that it starts in a specific profile. An example of the command is this:

`chrome.exe --profile-directory="Default" https://stackoverflow.com`

The above code will launch this site, while using the profile-directory "Default" which is the default profile for Chrome. You can substitute `"Default"` with any other profile-directory. However, the name for the directory is not the same as the one set in the profile inside of the browser. All manually created profile-directories are named `Profile #` where `#` is a digit increasing from `1` for each created profile.

For example, I have created the following two profiles:

[image: Chrome Profiles]

The default path for the Profiles is:

`C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\`

Looking in the folder I can find two folders named:

```
Profile 1\
Profile 2\
```

To make it easier to determine what user corresponds with which folder, you can open the file `Preferences` inside of each of those folders. Inside of that JSON-File, you can search for the `key` `"name":` which will contain the name you've set inside of the GUI.

After you've determined what folders are for the profile you want, then we can create the hotkey we're after:

```
^q::
Run, chrome.exe --profile-directory="Default" https://stackoverflow.com/
Run, chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 1" https://superuser.com/
Run, chrome.exe --profile-directory="Profile 2" https://www.google.com/ https://www.duckduckgo.com/
```